# Is there a better way than AllowHtml attribute to allow user to input < followed by a letter in textbox ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I see this approach to allow html in a user input field:
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/995931/Preventing-XSS-Attacks-in-ASP-NET-MVC-using-Valida

BUT what I need is not to allow HTML, I only need the user to be able to input < followed by some letters.

Is there not any solution better than [AllowHtml] for this case?

Answer (score 3):

There is if security is your concern. Keep the [AllowHtml] attribute and then sanitize the particular property where the [AllowHtml] attribute was applied.

I personally use [HtmlSanitizer](https://github.com/mganss/HtmlSanitizer) which you can get from NuGet

```
pm > Install-Package HtmlSanitizer
```

The example usage below is referenced from their actual GitHub page (linked above).

```
var sanitizer = new HtmlSanitizer();
var html = 
    @"<script>alert('xss')</script><div onload=""alert('xss')""" +
    @"style=""background-color: test"">Test<img src=""test.gif""" +
    @"style=""background-image: url(javascript:alert('xss')); margin: 10px""></div>";

var sanitized = sanitizer.Sanitize(html, "http://www.example.com");

Assert.That(sanitized, Is.EqualTo(@"<div style=""background-color: test"">"
    + @"Test<img style=""margin: 10px"" src=""http://www.example.com/test.gif""></div>"));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are sanitizing the input on the server (usually by default in ASP.NET), you could use a little bit of Javascript in your view, before submitting the form, to encode the HTML characters.

```
function Encode(text)
{
    var e = document.createElement("div");
    e.innerText = e.textContent = text;
    text = e.innerHTML;
    return text;
}

console.log(Encode("<asd"));
```

You can use the `onsubmit` event to replace the element value before the submission of the form.

Here is an example of the code in action: https://jsfiddle.net/496zz5hv/3/.

Comment: If this is the only check it looks like the server will depend on the user not being malicious. Always sanitize on the server as well.

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd Thanks for the heads up (updated my answer), although I was expecting the OP not to use AllowHtml attribute with this method.

Comment: I upvoted, as client manipulation of the input could guide me to a good approach. But this specific manipulation you are suggesting makes the user input unreadable. For example my user may input a mathematics formula a<b and it would display a&lt;b

Comment: @cnom in the example it only shows that on submission of the form. You could pass it to a Hidden element instead and pass that to the server. Also .NET provides the ability to decode and encode HTML (which you could do on the server side), https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5fyk1k(v=vs.110).aspx.